# Datetime Error on Newsletter Template

Tags: magento2, datetime, construct, magento2.3

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Go to `Admin->Marketing->Newsletter` Template
2. Select **Queue Newsletter** from right dropdown
3. Select a **Queue Date Start** and try to save it

**Expected Result**

1. Saved

**Actual result**

1. `DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (29/giu/2016 01:22:19) at position 0 (2): Unexpected character`

Comment: Do you get any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is fixed in Magento 2.3.0. Please review below links for other version
https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/15783/files
https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/18083/files.